# PC Wifi turns off when I connect to Samsung Smart TV via HDMI

Tags: wifi, television, hdmi, amd-gpu

I recently bought a Samsung Smart TV and wanted to hook it up to my PC as a second monitor. However every time I connect to it my WIFI drops out and will no longer connect to my home network or if it does it doesn't load web pages.

I'm using Windows 7 and my graphics card is an AMD 7970. There are four ports on there. I am using the DVI to my main monitor and HDMI to the TV. The two DisplayPort ports are unused.

Can anyone think of why this would be happening and how I could solve it?
I have tried connecting to both monitors at the same time and only to the TV via HDMI. In both these cases the wifi suffers the same problems. When I connect just to my monitor via DVI everything works perfectly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Samsung TV menu and turn off SWL(Samsung Wireless Link).  You may need to turn off other wireless options in the TV as well, but start there.  When the Smart TV is connected via HDMI to a CEC source, SWL automatically goes active.  It is intended as a direct WiFi link but the signal is so strong that it swamps other WiFi signals in the area.  It does not play well with others.

Comment: Thanks, the problem turned out to be a faulty HDMI to DVI adapter that was causing interference with my WiFi card. Once the adapter was unplugged and moved away it was fine. After wrapping alumunium foil around the exposed metal parts on the adapter it resolved the issue until I bought a new cable.